# Flex Image is not loading Dynamically

Tags: image, apache-flex

I am making a mobile app that will show users an image. Image is appearing witout a problem with this code:

```
<s:Image id="img" width="100%" source="assets/images/2.jpg"/>
```

But when I try to set the source property of Image like this:

```
function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    img.source = "assets/images/2.jpg";
}

<s:Image id="img" width="100%" />
```

the image is not appearing without error.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I just want to change image's source at runtime.

Comment: Are you sure the button1_clickHandler is executing properly?  Did you put a breakpoint in there?

Comment: I know this sounds crazy but it's solved after I close and reopen Flash Builder

Comment: Doesn't sound crazy at all: FlashBuilder is pretty crappy software when it comes to these things.

Comment: If I had to guess than I'd guess that there was an issue with your project not building properly. Sometimes Flash Builder does wonky things like that--I see that issue most commonly if I recompile the project during an active debug session.  A project clean may also have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after restarting Flash Builder